# Multiple async coroutine to reduce executed time in Kotlin

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

I had a list and I want to perform 1 heavy task with all elements to minimum executed times.
My solution is create a number of coroutines that equals to elements in list with dispatcher Default.

Example:

```
list.map {
   async {
      // do heavy task
   }
}.awaitAll()
```

Assume that I had a map with 500 elements and my device has maximum 4 threads that can run parallel maximum 4 heavy tasks. As my understanding that will 4 threads do 4 tasks parallel, when one thread executed done, one task will be allocated to that thread and start. The other solution is create 4 coroutines for 4 threads and sequentially do 125 task per thread. Each threads run sequentially therefore it confined multiple time to allocate task to threads. Therefore it faster than my solution. Is it right?
If not, what is the best solution?

Comment: Looks to me like these would be almost the same, with the first method having cleaner code at the tiny expense of creating function objects for each item.

Comment: Yes, task will run sequentially after 4 task haven't been finished. However you can employ Dispatchers.IO for 64 threads at max, so the task may be better scheduled by the OS to get the maximum benefit.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Yes, I know that. I just talk about performance, in my assumption the 2nd solution seems like faster cause of it just 4 times it allocate task to 4 threads. Meanwhile the 1st solution system will allocate task whenever thread finish task

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code.

It's for a List of a lot of elements that I need to transform into another object class.

```
/**
     * Method that converts the [FullStopsInfo] list into [Station] list.
     */
    private fun fastConvert(data: MutableList<FullStopsInfo>): Vector<Station> {
        var data1 = data
        val stations = Vector<Station>()

        var offset = 0
        val range = data1.size / Utils.availableCores()// your 4 cores

        val queue = mutableListOf<Deferred<Int>?>()

        val timeProccessing = measureTimeMillis {
            while (data1.isNotEmpty()) {
                val newRange = min(if(range == 0) 1 else range, data1.size)
                val tempTransfers = data1.subList(0, newRange)

                val preferredTask = addToList(tempTransfers, stations)//the transformation goes here
                queue.add(preferredTask)
                preferredTask.start()

                // Move to the next range
                data1 = data1.subList(newRange, data1.size)
                offset += newRange
            }

            runBlocking {
                queue.forEach {
                    it?.await()//wait until all procceses ended
                }
            }
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "End findSearchAllFullDataStation with $timeProccessing")
        return stations
    }
```